# How to get rid of "This declaration needs opt-in" warnings?

Tags: android

I want to get rid of these warnings in my code:

```
This declaration needs opt-in. Its usage should be marked with '@kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi' or '@OptIn(kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)'
```

I've tried to include this in my module's build.gradle.kts:

```
android {
    kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs += listOf("-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn")
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.